# How can i add this library to my android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add that library to my android studio project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tBkb.png)

How can i do that ?

Appreciate any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- File -> New -> Import Module...
- Select the source directory of the Module you want then click Finish.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your help